# Unable to complete Go Live process

Tags: docusignapi

I'm attempting to promote my development environment to live but the API transaction results keep failing at the 1st hurdle of '20 or more API transactions'.

I've pushed through about 40 envelopes (and signed them) from my development site so I presume that I've fulfilled this criteria.

The Docusign support team advised me to post the question here (!), so does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 0):

1. The 40 envelopes must be done via your app, not via UI.
2. You cannot use a token from the token generator. Must use auth via your app (JWT, Auth Code Grant etc.)